# jit_nodeValue_4(...).$any is not a function Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

```
ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_4(...).$any is not a function
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AddNewConnectionsComponent.html:42)
at handleEvent (core.js:13581)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15090)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14677)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:9990)
at eval (core.js:10611)
at HTMLInputElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4744)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
```

I am getting this error on required filed of form group.

My ts file code

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'
         import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";

     @Component({
   selector: 'app-add-new-connections',
 templateUrl: './add-new-connections.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./add-new-connections.component.scss']
})
export class AddNewConnectionsComponent {

 addNewConnectionForm: any;

 constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) { 
 this.addNewConnectionForm = new FormGroup({
  'connection_name': new FormControl("", [
    Validators.required
  ])
});
```

My Html file code

```
<form [formGroup]="addNewConnectionForm" (ngSubmit)="saveConnection()" novalidate>
            <div class="col-sm-4"> 
<div class="form-group">
                  <label>Connection Name ?</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" (change)="changeFun()" class="form-control" required>
                  <div *ngIf=>
                      Name is required.
                    </div>
                  <small [hidden]="addNewConnectionForm.controls.connection_name.valid" class="text-danger">Required</small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!addNewConnectionForm.valid">Submit</button>
          </form>
```

I have tried almost everything avalible. But I am not able to find any solution 
I have imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in my app.module.ts file
Can you please suggest me a way how i can do it

Comment: Having the same issue after deleting the node modules folder and doing a npm install

Comment: @arpit, please mark answer as correct!

Answer (score 52):

For me the issue was different.

I was using Angular material menu.
In the template the menu declared a local variable like this `<mat-menu #share='matMenu'>`.
`share` was also the name of the function I wanted to call in the component, which was now overwritten. Changing one of the names fixed this.

Comment: Oh man, I wasted my whole weekend on this issue. Thank you So much. I wish I could do more ups to this answer. :)

Comment: Name collision issue

Answer (score 10):

This normally happens when you've got two references of different data types with the same name. So you might have a Template Reference Variable of `#logout` and a button that calls `logout()` on click. Clicking the button would throw an error like the one you're getting.

Answer (score 4):

Using the command line go to the same directory as the `package.json` file of the application that you want to update.

Run `npm outdated` and you will see a list of packages that need updating. My app is fairly new so updating all was not an issue (if you need to update specific packages [this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127863/node-update-a-specific-package)). To do a full update run `npm update`, if you re-run `npm outdated` you will see everything is up to date, *BUT* you application may not compile now. The error message I got wasn't very helpful. To resolve this problem check all your import statement are still valid (one of mine was altered in app.module.ts)

`import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';` was changed to `import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';`

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am getting same issue in Angular 5 and I updated npm package by `npm update` and problem resolved for me, there was some issue in angular dependencies so I updated it.