# How to upgrade my global vue-cli install to the latest version?

Tags: ubuntu, vue.js, nvm, vue-cli-3

I already have vue-cli 3.5.5 installed. When I run `vue create myapp`, it shows message `Update available 3.6.2`.

```
Vue CLI v3.5.5
┌───────────────────────────┐
│  Update available: 3.6.2  │
└───────────────────────────┘
```

How to upgrade vue-cli to the latest version?

When I run `npm i -g vue-cli` it installs vue-cli version 2.9.6 instead of upgrading the existing vue cli version.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1.

node version: 10.15.3.

nvm version: 0.34.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node update a specific package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127863/node-update-a-specific-package)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

vue-cli 3.x is changed to @vue/cli. Therefore, no direct upgrade exists.

1. Uninstall old version if you no longer need it, or if latest install command gives error:

```
npm uninstall -g vue-cli
```

2. Use the following command to install the latest vue-cli version:

```
$ npm install -g @vue/cli@latest
```

### Notes

1. Do not run `$ npm i -g vue-cli` because vue-cli 3.x is changed to @vue/cli.
2. The vue-cli update [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/212) states that either `npm` or `yarn` can be used to upgrade vue-cli.
   However, when working within `nvm`, the yarn command `yarn global add @vue/cli` did not work.
   If you do not use `nvm` then installing via `yarn` might work. However, I did not verify this.

Comment: @Cosmos are you using `nvm` or not? For me, `yarn add` did not work with `nvm`.

Comment: I am not using nvm.

Comment: @Cosmos thank you for your response, good to know that `yarn add` works when you do not use `nvm`.

Comment: After reinstalling don't forget to exit the terminal session and enter a new one to use the new version.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone still having this issue I ran through the following steps:

1. Switched to latest stable Node.js release using [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

   `nvm install 14.16.0`
2. Uninstalled previous @vue/cli package

   `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`

   `npm uninstall -g vue-cli (v2.* and older)`
3. Globally installed latest stable release

   `npm install -g @vue/cli@latest`
4. Opened a new terminal window for the change to take effect; checked the version by running below command

   `vue --version`

Kudos to Antony for his original answer.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Vuejs - doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#upgrading), you can update it like this :

```
npm update -g @vue/cli

# OR

yarn global upgrade --latest @vue/cli
```

Answer (score 3):

first uninstall current vue version

`npm uninstall -g vue-cli`

then install vue

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue on Linux Mint 20. I tried everything possible to npm/yarn reinstall vue-cli or @vue/cli without success; it was always version 2.9.6. So the problem appeared to be wrong vue link instead of the vue-cli version. What did the trick was the command:

```
whereis vue
```

which showed two vue binaries:

```
vue: /usr/local/bin/vue /opt/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/bin/vue
```

so changing the vue link from `vue -> ../lib/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue` to `vue -> /opt/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/bin/vue` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> npm install -g @vue/cli
> ```

## OR

> ```
> yarn global add @vue/cli
> ```

Answer (score -2):

I, you can directly update your vucli but the best way is to delete the old version and install a new version ( it will be up to date). Use what you want. Delete and reinstall or upgrade directly.