# How do install using npm where version is latest in package.json (without manual edit or upgrade)

Tags: npm

I have tried installing in a couple ways...

```
npm install -S vue@*
npm install -S vue@latest
```

However, in the package.json they don't use * or latest, there is an actual version. I also don't want to have to manually edit this for each dependency. I also don't want to have to run an upgrade command in npm, I want it to be latest from initial install. How do I install in a way where the version is declared latest or *?

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest version of Vue into your dependencies do the following:

1) Remove `^` from the current version listed in `package.json`. `^` is the default semantic versioning used to lock your versions in place to avoid breaking changes.

2) run `npm update -s vue` to update your vue version to current.

Comment: Sorry this isn't what I was looking for I want the npm install command to USE latest I don't want to manually edit the package.json. I will make this clearer in the question.

Comment: Gotcha, this may be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127863/node-update-a-specific-package

Comment: Meh, so I guess I am stuck just editing the file. It is strange there isn't a feature for this, maybe I should open an issue with node.

Comment: I would argue the inconvenience is worth the security in this case. It would be too easy to accidentally create breaking changes through an unintended major version upgrade, otherwise. For example, if you generated your project with `vue init` (from Vue CLI v2), there are likely webpack incompatibilities with a major version change of Vue in your project.

Comment: I prefer breaking changes due to upgrades. That is what the package-lock is for in my case for released versions. If an upgrade of a library breaks my app I typically want to know about it so I can make the call to either fix the issue or declare a version for now.

Comment: Also I am not using webpack I am using the ESM version. "import Vue from '/vue/vue.esm.browser.js'"

Answer (score 0):

There's no such feature in npm. You could use/alias a shell one-liner though

```sh
NPM_INSTALL=vue node -e "const fs = require('fs').promises; (async () => {const pj = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile('./package.json')); pj.dependencies[process.env.NPM_INSTALL] = '*'; fs.writeFile('./package.json', JSON.stringify(pj, null, 2))})()" && npm install
```

Another possibility might be to use [`npm-check-updates`](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates), which lets you upgrade all dependencies to the latest version with one command: `ncu -u`