# Cannot install npm package over old version

Tags: npm

I tried to install new npm package on old code but it did not work, I think because of old version. Anyway, I deleted the old version package.json and it did work again. Now, I want to know that If there is a way to update the old version or something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an update of the pacakage. Here is copy/past [of the answer on how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43127994/17781575):

Most of the time you can just [npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) (or [pnpm update](https://pnpm.io/cli/update) or [yarn upgrade](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade)) a module to get the latest non breaking changes **(respecting the semver specified in your package.json)** (<-- read that last part again).

```
npm update browser-sync
-------
pnpm update browser-sync
-------
yarn upgrade browser-sync
```

> - Use `[p]npm|yarn outdated` to see which modules have newer versions
> - Use `[p]npm update|yarn upgrade` (without a package name) to update all modules

**Major version upgrades:**

In your case, it looks like you want the next major version (v2.x.x), which is likely to have breaking changes and you will need to update your app to accommodate those changes. You can install/save the latest `2.x.x` by doing:

```
npm install browser-sync@2 --save-dev
-------
pnpm add browser-sync@2 --save-dev
-------
yarn add browser-sync@2 --dev
```

...or the latest `2.1.x` by doing:

```
npm install browser-sync@2.1 --save-dev
-------
pnpm add browser-sync@2.1 --save-dev
-------
yarn add browser-sync@2.1 --dev
```

...or the **latest and greatest** by doing:

```
npm install browser-sync@latest --save-dev
-------
pnpm add browser-sync@latest --save-dev
-------
yarn add browser-sync@latest --dev
```

> **Note:** the last one is no different than doing this:
>
> ```
> npm uninstall browser-sync --save-dev
> npm install browser-sync --save-dev
> -------
> pnpm remove browser-sync --save-dev
> pnpm add browser-sync --save-dev
> -------
> yarn remove browser-sync --dev
> yarn add browser-sync --dev
> ```
>
> The `--save-dev` part is important. This will uninstall it, remove the value from your package.json, and then reinstall the latest version and save the new value to your package.json.